# React Native router-flux reload the current scene

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am using react-native-router-flux for navigation. I get a array of data in a scene, and I am rendering them in a scrollView with a component. In that component there is a delete method for that data. When a user delete a data, I need to reload the scene to get the new datas, and render them. How can I reload the current scene.

This is the code for render.

```
<ScrollView style={styles.topContainer}>
    <Header headerText={'Tasks'} />
      {this.renderTasksDetails()}
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <AddButton onPress={() => Actions.addTasks({ text: this.props.text })}> + </AddButton>
    </View>
</ScrollView>
```

And the renderTaskDetail function

```
return this.state.tasks.map(task =>
  <TaskDetail key={task.metin} task={task} text2={this.props.text} />);
```

As I said I have a array of data, thats why I map it to a another component(TaskDetail).

And the delete method in the other component I fetch then I call Actions for refresh.

```
fetch(URL, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    },
    body: formBody
  }).then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    console.log(responseJson);
    console.log(responseJson.stat);
    if (responseJson.stat === 'ok') {
      Actions.refresh({ text: text2 });//What to do for reload
   }
```

What can I do to refresh the current scene. I tried to go to the same scene but it does nothing because i am already at that scene.

Edit : router.js

```
<Scene key="main">
    <Scene key="tasks" hideNavBar={true} component={Tasks} initial />
    <Scene key="addTasks" component={AddTask} title='Task Create' />
</Scene>
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply use this:

```
Actions.refresh({key: Math.random()});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

```
Actions.refresh({ whatever_props_you_need: whatever_props_value, key: moment() });
```

The main point here is the **key: moment()**. As I always set as current time, so every time you refresh it will detect the key as a new value, so the page will refresh. Or you can just use any unique string for the key props replacing moment().

Hope it helps :)